# Stack Overflow timeline (feeds) of a user

Tags: stackexchange-api, stackexchange

How to get the Stack Overflow timeline (feeds) of a user?

What are the steps to follow, if a user wants to display his or others Stack Overflow timeline/feeds in his website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This document details the steps to get the Stack Overflow timeline (feeds) of a user.

**Example:** A live example is available in

> https://newtonjoshua.com

**Stack Overflow:**
Stack Overflow is a site of Stack Exchange, a network of Q&A websites.

> http://stackexchange.com

**Stack Exchange API:**
We can use the Stack Exchange API to return a subset of the actions the user/users have taken on the site.

> https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

**Timeline Feed:**

> https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/timeline-on-users

Enter the ids of the user (eg: 6778969) to view the timeline of the user.
The complete url for the GET request will look like,

> https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/6778969/timeline?site=stackoverflow

**Code snippet:**

```
//You can replace the timeline_type with a detailed descrition as given below.
var timelineType = {
    accepted: 'Accepted An Answer',
    answered: 'Posted An Answer',
    asked: 'Asked A Question',
    badge: 'Earned A Badge',
    commented: 'Posted A Comment',
    reviewed: 'Reviewed A Suggested Edit',
    revision: 'Edited A Post',
    suggested: 'Suggested An Edit'
};

var formattedFeeds = [];

$.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/6778969/timeline?site=stackoverflow&filter=!))x30_z', function (feeds) {
        feeds.items.forEach(function (feed) {
        var formattedFeed = {};
        formattedFeed.timeline_type = timelineType[feed.timeline_type];
        formattedFeed.title = feed.title || feed.detail;
        formattedFeed.detail = feed.detail || '';
        formattedFeed.creation_date = new Date(feed.creation_date * 1000);
        formattedFeeds.push(formattedFeed); 
    });
});
```

You can display the contents of formattedFeeds in your website.

Comment: Is there any way to sort the timeline items by type on the server? I just want to get the object with certain `timeline_type`.